# How resize a video in video editor while keeping timeline?

Tags: canvas, video, resize

When I resize my video in the video editor, it reloads and I lose the timeline at the bottom. When this happens I can no longer adjust the timing of the animations for other text fields.

How can I resize my video without losing my timeline **OR** start a video project with specific dimensions?

Any help would be great!